# When selecting an amount of rows, how can I select a percentage of a percentage?

Tags: php, mysql

Fairly simple question:

Say I want to use 30 percent of the rows in the table of my MySQL table.

However I also have a user input where they can select a percentage of that percentage

For example: `$_GET['percentage']% of 30%`

so we say that `$_GET['percentage'] = 30`

How would I select 30% `(or $_GET['percentage'])` of 30% to use in a while loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

30% of *any* value is that value multiplied by 0.3.

So 30% of 30% is `0.3 * 0.3 = 0.09`, or 9%.

Substitute in whatever numbers you desire.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. I was racking my brain all night trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication?

```
.3 * $_GET['percentage'] / 100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysql_num_rows` or `PDOStatement::rowCount` depending on which library your using to get the number of rows returned by the query and then simple multiplication can tell you how many times you should call `mysql_fetch_row` or `PDOStatement::fetch`.